# Virtualbox doesn't open - error VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY

Tags: virtual-machine

I had tried to install an OS named Veos with virtual box ,but when I had finished the installation ,I can not open the wirtual machine Veos ,and I had this output:
 Failed to open image 'C:\Users\Takfarinas\VirtualBox VMs\AristaFiles\vEOS-lab-4.16.6M.vmdk' for writing due to wrong permissions (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).
Failed to attach driver below us! Image is read-only. (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).
PIIX3 cannot attach drive to the Primary Master (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).

Code d'erreur : 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Composant : 
ConsoleWrap
Interface : 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Answer (score 13):

Right click on the .vdi file .
Click on properties .
Just uncheck Read only . 
And start VirtualBox with administrator priviligies.
This done the trick for me . :)

Comment: Worked for me -- I had copied the Windows XP Mode .vhd file, but didn't realize it was marked with the read-only attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Error message:

> Failed to open image 'C:\Windows XP Mode\VirtualXP.VHD' for writing due to wrong permissions

Things to try:

1. ?? Grant "Full control" permission to the user (*properties > security*)
2. ?? Run VirtualBox as administrator
3. **Solution: Unmount the virtual hard disk in your current OS (by clicking on "Eject")**

*How to unmount the virtual hard disk:*

[image]

Comment: Unmounting the virtual hard disk worked *(and was all I had to do)*. **This is the correct answer.**

Comment: I also need to restart virtual box after the unmount and mount of network disk (not virtualbox disk).

Answer (score 4):

It seems you use Windows OS, as Host OS. Try to run Virtualbox as Administrator. Right click on Virtualbox ICON and "run as Administrator".
Or change the rights of Virtualbox. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have suffered from the same problem recently.
I changed the permissions of my visual disk image.Then It works.

1.Right click your .vdi file.
2.Select property item in the popup menu.
3.Swith to security tab.Select users then click Edit button.
4.Check on full control.

Answer (score 1):

This happens on our work airgap machine when someone forgets to shut down the virtual machine at the end of their session. Restarting the machine resolves the issue, for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me with **Win 11**, giving **full control to current user** in security tab of **.vdi** file and then **uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox**, worked.

Reference to the original thread [(Solved) VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=41730)

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the `VBoxSDS` service did the trick for me.

```
net stop  VBoxSDS
net start VBoxSDS
```

Comment: Confirmed. Can also be done through the services UI, where it is named "VirtualBox system service".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu HOST on MacOS client and having the same problem...
I think the file directory on my storage (/mnt/HARDISK) may have some problem...but using the following command can solve

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /mnt/HARDDISK
```

See if it works

#ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try the link to move a vdi to another drive - UUID may prevent it from loading

```
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-move-virtualbox-vms-from-one-drive-to-another/#:~:text=1%20How%20to%20move%20VirtualBox%20VMs%20from%20one,moved%20your%20VirtualBox%20virtual%20machine...%205%20Also%20see.
```

Alternatively, clone the image and open the clone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by

1. in the Storage tab of the Virtualbox virtual machine settings, I detached the disk image from the virtual machine,
2. in the Virtual Tools screen, I copied the *.vdi disk to a new *vdi disk image,
3. in the Virtual Tools screen, I moved the old disk image to a new name, and then moved the new disk image to the original disk image name.
4. in the Storage tab of the Virtualbox virtual machine settings, I attached  the new disk image to the virtual machine.

After that, the virtual machine started as desired.